# Trying to repeat capture block in JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my body below. Basically each block is separated by a line with nothing on it. Each block has a title in brackets, and then can have any number of properties which are in format of word on left, then equals, then words on right.

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=0

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/vr10qb8s.default
Default=1

[Profile1]
Name=cleanER One Here
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/k46wtieb.cleanER One Here
```

I'm trying to get 3 matches. Each should look like: [whole match,title,prop1,val1,propN,valN]

Match1:

```
['[General]
StartWithLastProfile=0','General','StartWithLastProfile','0']
```

Match2:

```
['[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/vr10qb8s.default
Default=1','Profile0','Name','default','IsRelative','1','Path','Profiles/vr10qb8s.default','Default','1']
```

and so on.

So this was my regex:

```
       var patt = /\[.*\](?:\s+?([\S]+)=([\S]+)+/mg;
       var blocks = [];

       var match;
       while (match = patt.exec(readStr)) {
        console.log(match)
       }
```

but this is spitting out out: `[whole match, title, propLAST, valLAST];`. If I change the last + in the regex patt to +? then it gives `[whole match, title, propFIRST, valFIRST];`.

This regex works but with a gimmick:

```
var patt = /\[.*\](?:\s+?([\S]+)=([\S]+))(?:\s+?([\S]+)=([\S]+))?(?:\s+?([\S]+)=([\S]+))?(?:\s+?([\S]+)=([\S]+))?(?:\s+?([\S]+)=([\S]+))?/mg;
```

This now returns:

```
[ "[General]
StartWithLastProfile=0", "StartWithLastProfile", "0", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 1 more… ]

[ "[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/vr10qb8s.default
Default=1", "Name", "default", "IsRelative", "1", "Path", "Profiles/vr10qb8s.default", "Default", "1", undefined, 1 more… ]

[ "[Profile1]
Name=cleanER
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/k46wtieb.clean", "Name", "cleanER", "IsRelative", "1", "Path", "Profiles/k46wtieb.clean", undefined, undefined, undefined, 1 more… ]
```

I don't want those unnecessary undefineds at the end, and this pattern is limited to how many of the `(?:\s+?([\S]+)=([\S]+))?` I paste at the end of the pattern

Answer (score 0):

### [LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fotinela/1/edit)

### JavaScript Code

```
string = string.split(/\n\n/g); // split along the double newline to get blocks

var matches = [];  // the complete matches array has `match1`, `match2`, etc.

string.forEach(function(elem, index){ // for each block
  var matchArr = [];               // make a matchArr

  matchArr.push(elem); // wholeMatch 

  elem.replace(/\[([a-z0-9]+)\]/i, function(match, $1){    
    matchArr.push($1); // get the title  
  });

  elem.replace(/([a-z]+)=(.+)/ig, function(match, $1, $2){
    matchArr.push($1); // property
    matchArr.push($2); // value
  });

  matches.push(matchArr);  // push the `match` in bigger `matches` array
});

console.log(matches); // get the whole matches array

// You can use `matches[0]` to get the 1st match, and so on.
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ah thanks for this, but I was looking for a pure regex solution though.

Comment: Oh, then, I am thinking for that method.

Comment: Much thanks for your initative its midnight here so Ill take a nap haha thx man!

Comment: @Noitidart Cool ! it's afternoon here :D